# In awk, can you use a pattern AND an END block together?

Tags: awk

In awk, you can perform an action for a given pattern, like:

```
echo foo | awk '/foo/ {print "foo"}'
```

or you can perform an action at the end of the input, like:

```
echo foo | awk 'END {print "END"}'
```

But it does not appear to be possible to do both, like:

```
# echo foo | awk '/foo/ || END {print "foo or END"}'
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    /foo/ || >>>  END <<<  {print "foo or END"}
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You would just put the same command in both the `/foo/` and the `END` blocks like `awk '/food/{print "foo or END"}END{print "foo or END"}` if the logic in the block is sufficiently comples then you can move it to a function and call the function from both blocks.

Comment: Understood, but if the block is long, then it's a lot of redundant code...

Comment: Right, so stick that code into a function and call the function from both blocks. If it's sufficiently complex consider writing this as a proper `.awk` file and executing like `awk -f myawkscript.awk myfile.txt`

Comment: Forgot awk had functions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

No. Do this instead:

```
awk '
/foo/ { prtInfo() }
END   { prtInfo() }
function prtInfo() { print "foo or END" }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this workaround

```
awk '{Last=$0} END{ if( Last ~ /foo/) print "action if" }' YourFile
```

but it's only for last line of last file

Answer (score 0):

this might be simpler

```
$ awk '/foo/{exit} END{print "foo or END"}'
```

`exit` will run the `END` block, so you don't need to repeat the statement.

Comment: Mmmm... that will ignore any lines following `foo`, surely?

Comment: Yes, of course early exit.  The question as I understand,  find a "foo" or no "foo" at the end.  If you want to find all "foo"s this is not the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do such a thing. The `END` statements are executed when the last line has been processed and similar to `BEGIN` they are special forms of patterns.

> **Overall Program Structure**
>
> An awk program is composed of pairs of the
>   form:
>
> ```
> pattern { action }
> ```
>
> Either the `pattern` or the `action` (including the enclosing brace
>   characters) can be omitted.
>
> **Patterns**
>
> A pattern is any valid expression, a range specified by two expressions separated by a comma, **or one of the two special patterns `BEGIN` or `END`**.
>
> *Special Patterns*
>
> The awk utility shall recognize two special patterns, `BEGIN` and `END`. Each `BEGIN` pattern shall be matched once and its associated action executed before the first record of input is read-except possibly by use of the `getline` function (see Input/Output and General Functions) in a prior `BEGIN` action-and before command line assignment is done. Each `END` pattern shall be matched once and its associated action executed after the last record of input has been read. These two patterns shall have associated actions.
>
> **`BEGIN` and `END` shall not combine with other patterns.** Multiple `BEGIN` and `END` patterns shall be allowed. The actions associated with the `BEGIN` patterns shall be executed in the order specified in the program, as are the `END` actions. An `END` pattern can precede a `BEGIN` pattern in a program.
>
> **<sub>source: [awk POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)</sub>**

The statement

```
/foo/ || END { action }
```

is thus not allowed as it combines `END` with another pattern.

See the answer of Ed Morton for an elegant solution.